# PySpark split DataFame on column value in parallel

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Update: Added `repartition` & `persist`.

I've a dataframe (data that is sourced from json) that contains a column named `table` that i need to essentially use to split into multiple, different new dataframes. Some sample data:

```
+--------------+-------------+
|         table|    timestamp|
+--------------+-------------+
|       A_TABLE|1573085110000|
|       A_TABLE|1573171204000|
|       A_TABLE|1572912308000|
|AN_OTHER_TABLE|1573171513000|
|AN_OTHER_TABLE|1572912020000|
|AN_OTHER_TABLE|1573084819000|
+--------------+-------------+
```

I don't know how how many distinct values there are going to be in col `table`, and i also don't know what they will actually contain.. I considered partitioning my original dataframe on `table`, but i don't think that is viable as i need to subsequently pivot the data.. and they all differ.

So, i did this, which by my own admission is a bit meh:

```
# Repartition & persist
df = df.repartition("table")
df.persist()

tblNames = [row.table for row in df.select("table").distinct().collect()]

# Split the frame..
for tblName in tblNames:
  filtered_df = df.filter(df.table == tblName)

  # Do some work with 'filtered_df', a bit of exploding, pivoting, etc..
  # This results in a new dataframe, here named out_df

  # output
  out_path = "/mnt/path/auto/"+ tblName +"/"  
  out_df.write.format("delta").save(out_path)
```

Right now, this is 'ok', as i only have a handful of things that need to be split. But i can't help but think this simply won't scale.

Is there a smart way to restructure this, so that perhaps the operation is completed in parallel.. am i correct in thinking that this is running on the head node too?

I considered doing something like this, not sure if i gain anything by using rdd though, other than reduced readability!:

```
tblNames = df.select("table").distinct().rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
dfs = [df.filter(df.table == tblName) for tblName in tblNames]

dfs[0].show() # Now i need to loop through these.. have i gained anything?
```

Closing thought.. maybe i could move all the 'work' to a udf, or something.. and run it on each of the dataframes in the `dfs` array concurrently?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you add a little more details -- are `table`s Hive tables? what Spark version?

Comment: thanks @mazaneicha, i have tried to clarify a bit in the open portion of the q. There are no hive tables in question here, this is simply a 'data frame containing data', i think i might have confused things by using the term `table`..

Spark version is 2.4.3 running under Databricks, but can make it any version as it's only be using the cluster! 

Comment: thanks for making it clearer, because initially I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Two things here: An obvious perf improvement is to `repartition` `df` by `table` and then `persist` or `checkpoint`. Then all subsequent filter operations on `table` column will be much faster. 
Regarding scalability, if you have so many unique elements in `table` column that it will cause memory issue when collected to the driver node, then how can you expect to have that many reference variables to each dataframe that you end up creating. What are you trying to achieve *after* splitting the original df into multiple dataframes?

Comment: sure. After they are split to multiple dataframes, the data runs through the same series of operations but will ultimately yield different results.. two most important ones are to pivot the rows to columns, so if they remain together the cols will be unknown number.. and the other is to correct/change/cast datatypes.. which again, could differ for the same column name.. the results are then subject to an upsert w. existing data originating with the same `table` col.